# Which preposition should I put before a season?

Tags: prepositions

1. over the autumn
2. in the autumn
3. during the autumn

Example: Over/In/During the autumn, the company embarked on the next stage of its efforts to boost efficiency, which are aimed at better equipping the operation for future challenges.

Which preposition should I use in front of 'the autumn'?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. You have not provided [sufficient context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) to provide an answer, as what preposition you use would depend on what it is you are trying to say. It  could be *throughout the autumn* or *into the autumn* or *towards the autumn* among others, and that is just for indications of time. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for some guidance on writing strong questions, and to [edit] your post to include more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still haven't indicated what you're trying to express. Is it a period of time entirely within the autumn? Does it extend for the whole duration of the autumn? Does it extend into the summer before or the winter after?

Comment: Sorry I could not add more. Because I am the reader of the article, not the writer. I saw a mix of prepositions before the season and got confused.

Comment: I don't understand—if you are the reader, why are you asking which preposition *you* would use? Any of those prepositions is acceptable, but they can mean different things, and there are perhaps a dozen other prepositions of time that would also be acceptable.

Comment: If it's an article, what does it *actually* say? Provide a quote and a link. Then indicate why you think the preposition it uses is wrong. If this actually *is* what it says, then it's likely not an article but some kind of test or grammar site—and there is more context than just what's given here. (Which is why a link would be useful.)

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information about your sentence, but generally `in` is used before seasons.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your example, "Over the autumn" scans better as a sentence and would be my preferred choice. "During" is valid too, but Over would likely be more commonly used.